# comparing two protocol for different values in R

Tags: r

I have this data set:

```
Experiment,Method,Values,Mean
10,IEEE802.11P,1,1
10,IEEE802.11P,5,2
10,IEEE802.11P,10,3
20,IEEE802.11P,1,4
20,IEEE802.11P,5,5
20,IEEE802.11P,10,6
40,IEEE802.11P,1,7
40,IEEE802.11P,5,8
40,IEEE802.11P,10,9
60,IEEE802.11P,1,10
60,IEEE802.11P,5,11
60,IEEE802.11P,10,12
80,IEEE802.11P,1,13
80,IEEE802.11P,5,14
80,IEEE802.11P,10,15
10,DTB-MAC,1,16
10,DTB-MAC,5,17
10,DTB-MAC,10,18
20,DTB-MAC,1,19
20,DTB-MAC,5,20
20,DTB-MAC,10,21
40,DTB-MAC,1,22
40,DTB-MAC,5,23
40,DTB-MAC,10,24
60,DTB-MAC,1,25
60,DTB-MAC,5,26
60,DTB-MAC,10,27
80,DTB-MAC,1,28
80,DTB-MAC,5,29
80,DTB-MAC,10,30
```

I actually want to compare `IEEE802.11P` and `DTB-MAC` for different values (1,5,10) in different situation (10,20,40,60,80)  and draw the graph all in one.

Any idea how to draw it with R?
I want to assign experiments to x axis and mean to y axis. and mix all of these information just in one graph.

I tried it as follow:

```
library(grid);
library(ggplot2);
library(reshape2);
pdf(file = '$filename.pdf', width=5, height=5);

dat <- read.csv('bdr.csv');

dat1 <- melt(dat,id.vars = c('Experiment','Method'));

ggplot(dat1,aes(factor(Experiment),value,fill=factor(variable)))+geom_line()+
      facet_grid(. ~ Method)+
      labs(x='$xlabel',y='$ylabel', fill='')+
    scale_fill_manual(values = c('red','lawngreen','deepskyblue'), labels = c('Values', 'Mean')) +
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 100), breaks = (seq(0,100,by = 5)))+
theme_bw()+
      theme(    panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = 'grey'),
    panel.border = element_rect(colour = 'black'),
axis.line = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank(), legend.position='top', legend.direction='horizontal', panel.margin = unit(1, 'lines'),legend.background = element_rect(colour = 'grey'));
```

Comment: Yes. I have some ideas. What have you tried?

Comment: yes you can find it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x = Experiment, y = Mean, colour = Method,
                linetype = as.factor(Values), shape = as.factor(Values))) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()
```

where `dat` is the name of your data frame.
[image]

Comment: thanks. but is there any way to mix all of them in on graph and also I want to assign experiments to x axis and mean to y axis.

Comment: thanks, i NEVER did it like this. Its exactly what I need.